# Open video file from File Explorer and playing in my videoplayer activity

Tags: android, file, video, explorer, video-player

I have my VideoPlayerActivity.java and I want to open when I press on a video file from my sdcard through my file explore or another application

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager.WifiLock;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.webkit.URLUtil;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.MediaController.MediaPlayerControl;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class VideoPlayerActivity extends Activity  implements  OnErrorListener, OnBufferingUpdateListener, 
    OnCompletionListener, OnPreparedListener, OnVideoSizeChangedListener, 
    MediaPlayerControl, SurfaceHolder.Callback, VideoControllerView.MediaPlayerControl, Runnable {


    private static final String TAG = "Player";



    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    SurfaceView playerSurfaceView;
    VideoControllerView controller;


    private int position;


    private String videoPath;



    int videoWidth, videoHeight;






    @Override        
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.video_player);
        playerSurfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.playersurface);


        surfaceHolder = playerSurfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

        videoPath = getIntent().getStringExtra("videoPath");


        // getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
       // getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


    public String getRealPathFromURI(Context context, Uri contentUri) {
          Cursor cursor = null;
          try { 
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri,  proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
          } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
              cursor.close();
            }
          }
        }





    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder arg0) {

        controller = new VideoControllerView(this);



          try {

            //  String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/yourfolderNAme/yopurfile.mp3";

              /*  final String path = mPath.getText().toString();
                Log.v(TAG, "path: " + path);

                if (path.equals(current) && mediaPlayer != null) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    return;
                }

                current = path;*/


             // Uri fileUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 166);

            //  Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");




                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
                mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
               // mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                mediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer vmp) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setClass(VideoPlayerActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }); 
                mediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);             
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoPath);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();

                Log.v(TAG, "Duration: ===>" + mediaPlayer.getDuration());
                mediaPlayer.start();

                mediaPlayer.setWakeMode(getApplicationContext(), PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK);
                WifiLock wifiLock = ((WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE))
                        .createWifiLock(WifiManager.WIFI_MODE_FULL, "mylock");
                    wifiLock.acquire();
                    wifiLock.release();

            } /*catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "error: "+ e.getMessage(), e);
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                }
            }*/

      catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void setDataSource(String path) throws IOException {

        if (!URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(path)) {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
        } else {
            URL url = new URL(path);
            URLConnection cn = url.openConnection();
            cn.connect();
            InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
            if (stream == null)
                throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
            File temp = File.createTempFile("mediaplayertmp", "dat");
            String tempPath = temp.getAbsolutePath();
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(temp);
            byte buf[] = new byte[2000];    
            do {
                int numread = stream.read(buf);
                if (numread <= 0)
                    break;
                out.write(buf, 0, numread);
            } while (true);

            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(tempPath);

            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
        }

    }

    private final Handler handler = new Handler (){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            final int currentPos = msg.getData().getInt("CurrentPosition");

        }

    };

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            controller.show();

            /*if(controller.isShowing()) {
            controller.hide();
        }else {
            controller.show();
        }*/
        return false;
    }


        @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onDestroy();
     if (mediaPlayer != null) {
         mediaPlayer.release();
         mediaPlayer = null; 
     }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     super.onPause();
     if (mediaPlayer != null) {
         mediaPlayer.release();
         mediaPlayer = null; 
     }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {

    }



   // Implement MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener    

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        controller.setMediaPlayer(this);
        controller.setAnchorView((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.videoSurfaceContainer));
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

 // End MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener

    // Implement VideoMediaController.MediaPlayerControl
    @Override
    public boolean canPause() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekBackward() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canSeekForward() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getBufferPercentage() {
        return 0;
    }

   @Override
    public int getCurrentPosition() {
     return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public int getDuration() {
        return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isPlaying() {
        return mediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void seekTo(int i) {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFullScreen() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void toggleFullScreen() {

    }
    // End VideoMediaController.MediaPlayerControl

    @Override
    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
     videoWidth = width;
     videoHeight = height;
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
       String.valueOf(videoWidth) + "x" + String.valueOf(videoHeight), 
       Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
      surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(videoWidth, videoHeight);
     }
    }

    @Override
    public int getAudioSessionId() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        controller = new VideoControllerView(this);

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoSrc);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         mediaPlayer.start();

        /* 
         Message msg = new Message();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("CurrentPosition", mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
            msg.setData(bundle);
            handler.sendMessage(msg);
        //  handler.postDelayed(callBack, 500);*/
        }


    public int getPosition() {
        return position;
    }


    public void setPosition(int position) {
        this.position = position;
    }


    }
```

And my logcat error is

```
01-03 20:42:14.881: V/MediaPlayer(14737): setVideoSurfaceTexture
01-03 20:42:14.881: W/System.err(14737): java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString
01-03 20:42:14.901: W/System.err(14737):    at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:468)
01-03 20:42:14.901: W/System.err(14737):    at android.net.Uri$StringUri.<init>(Uri.java:458)
01-03 20:42:14.901: W/System.err(14737):    at android.net.Uri.parse(Uri.java:430)
01-03 20:42:14.901: W/System.err(14737):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1256)
01-03 20:42:14.901: W/System.err(14737):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:1221)
```

My XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:keepScreenOn="true"
    android:id="@+id/video_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoSurfaceContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


       <SurfaceView
            android:id="@+id/playersurface"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

And one more question. I have this public void method for streaming

```
private void setDataSource(String path) throws IOException {

    if (!URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(path)) {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
    } else {
        URL url = new URL(path);
        URLConnection cn = url.openConnection();
        cn.connect();
        InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
        if (stream == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
        File temp = File.createTempFile("mediaplayertmp", "dat");
        String tempPath = temp.getAbsolutePath();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(temp);
        byte buf[] = new byte[2000];    
        do {
            int numread = stream.read(buf);
            if (numread <= 0)
                break;
            out.write(buf, 0, numread);
        } while (true);

        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(tempPath);

        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

}
```

How can I used to stream files from another application program?

When I play video from main activity it plays and when I quit and go to file explorer and chose my player from custom dialog box and open I have that problem with uriString...

Comment: where is videoControllerView interface

Comment: I have it...why?...btw I have a problem with controller...how can I make it, when press once on display appear my controller and when press twice disappear?

Answer (score 0):

When navigating through your files you can set a clicklistener on a thumbnail. I use this code to fire up a full-screen video editor:

```
        thumbNail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (pathType.equals("image")) {
                    <snip>
                }
                    else {
                            // music file
                    }
                else {
                    // must be video
                    Intent intent = new Intent();
                    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(cmsURL + pathListFull,"video/mp4");

                    PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
                    List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
                    boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;

                    if (isIntentSafe) {
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else {
                        Log.d("SHOWFILE", "no intents available");
                    }
                }

            }
        });
```

Comment: Hello Martin..thanks for reply...i viewed your post and i will test that code....i have another problem...i want when i press on a image with a streaming link to open that link in my activity player...how can be done...Thank you

Comment: Hello again...I've tested your code but doesn't work, or I don't know how to used(I'm at the beging with android :D)...I appreciate if u want to give some details about how to use that code...Thank you